# Unable to set bindings to BindableProperties in Partial Views using Xamarin Prism 7.1

Tags: xamarin, view, prism, partial, bindableproperty

I'm using the Partial Views feature of Prism 7.1 in Xamarin in which the ContentView can have its own ViewModel.  The binding to the viewmodel is working fine.  However, I would also like to set a BindableProperty. For example, I would like to set a Title property on the ContentView.  If the ContentView does not have its own ViewModel the Binding works fine.  If it does have its own ViewModel the binding never occurs.

```
MainPage.xaml
<controls:CustomContentView  Title="My Custom View Title"
    mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference self}"/>

CustomContentView.cs:
public static readonly BindableProperty TitleProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Title),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(CustomContentView));

public string Title
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
    set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
}

CustomContentView.xaml:
    <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Title}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

If I set a breakpoint on the Title's set method, it never gets hit and the Title in the Label control is never bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a Partial View your Binding Context is the ViewModel for the View not the View itself...

By setting the Label's text in the CustomContentView like:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
</StackLayout>
```

This would expect to bind to something like:

```
public class CustomContentViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get => _title;
        set => SetProperty(ref _title, value);
    }
}
```

Since you're instead expecting the binding to pull from the code behind, the XAML would need to be something like:

```
<ContentView x:Class="AwesomeApp.Views.CustomContentView"
             x:Name="self">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Title,Source={x:Reference self}}" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: The Label Source binding to self worked perfectly.   Thanks so much!